# Unable to connect to Event HUB from Service bus explorer

Tags: azureservicebus, azure-eventhub, service-bus-explorer

I have downloaded the Service Bus Explorer from GIT. I am able to connect to the Service Bus Queue & Topics. But when i am trying to connect to the Event Hub, i am getting some issue. Error-->
Exception: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized. claim is empty. There is no option to pass any claim. IN connection string also there is no such parameter.

Initially it was working but after i created a new Event hub tool stopped working

```
Failed to retrieve EventHub entities. Exception: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: The remote server returned an error: 
(401) Unauthorized. claim is empty. TrackingId:92ab37f6-452a-48c4-ae20-af7f0e64915b_G25, SystemTracker:ehn-g3ms-tutor.servicebus.windows.net:$Resources/EventHubs, Timestamp:2019-07-11T11:08:52 ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized
```

Comment: which connection string are you using?

Comment: currently i am using SAS  connection string for the respective policy. I am using the primary connection string

Answer (score 9):

Maybe you made the same mistake I did.
When you create an "Event Hub" you define: the 1)namespace and the 2)event hub. Both of them have their own "Shared access policies". Maybe you created the policies into the "Event Hub" and copied-and-pasted into "Service Bus Explorer". But the connection string you should use is named "RootManageSharedAccessKey" (located in the namespace)
[as you can see in this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W3iBS.png)